# Grails: Anything Like ASP.NET MVC EditorForModel()

Tags: grails, plugins, view

ASP.NET has a nifty method for its views called "EditorForModel()", where the passed in model is checked and for each property a default control (e.g. a textbox for a String) is put onto the page. This way, for a basic object that needs to be edited you can get a full Edit screen basically for free. This is not always what you want, obviously, but sometimes it is, especially for Admin type screens.

I don't see anything like this in the Grails framework, but I figured there could be a plugin or something that I was missing. Has anyone heard of anything like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `static scaffold = true` in your controller class you will not even need any view file (gsp) to get full edit screens for your model (domain class). It's handy for simple CRUD actions.

Answer (score 0):

Grails uses Scaffolding.  See the docs [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html).  Basically the same thing.  Still nifty.